# When can text/html be an "unsupported MIME type"?

Tags: microsoft-edge, mime-types, vod

**tl;dr** *Does anyone recalls any scenario or situation in which Microsoft Edge under Windows 11 claims that `text/html` is "unsupported MIME type"?*

---

I am trying to play [Polish VOD television](https://playnow.pl/) in the following gear:

- Microsoft Edge (*110.0.1587.63 64-bit*)
- Windows 11 (*Microsoft Windows 11 Pro 10.0.22621 Build 22621*)

This works like a charm in Chrome and Firefox (though you need to have a paid account and authenticate yourself). but in Edge this is not possible (I'm ending up with never-ending loader). This is most likely due to the fact that site has some [really weird problems and errors](https://superuser.com/q/1772430/156554).

Probably the same cause is causing that even though I have notifications enabled for this site:

[image]

Edge blocks them:

[image]

This site is owned by a company, who has 10 million customers, so I completely don't believe in that warnings. Neither those shown as a popup nor those [displayed in the console](https://superuser.com/q/1772430/156554) (especially given the fact that error in console points to a non-existing website!).

What matters me the most is that when click *Allow* nothing changes (i.e. VOD is still not being played, never-ending loader is still circling) and when I look again into console, I see this:

[image]

> The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

*Esquisse moi*, but what is going on here? How can `text/html` be an "unsupported MIME type"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error message in full (emphasis mine):

> **The script** has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')

Note how it says "**the script**", i.e. there's a `<script src="something.js">` where `something.js` is being served as `text/html` instead of `text/javascript` - this suggests it's a dynamically generated script and the server-code is showing a user-readable HTML error response instead (but is incorrectly serving it with a HTTP 200 OK status instead of 4xx or 5xx code).

Note, of course, that other languages besides JavaScript/ECMAScript can be used in web-pages (historically, that includes VBScript and Tcl), but Chrome (and the current HTML specification) only supports JavaScript/ECMAScript.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering how it is possible that the very same page (serving exactly the same content under exactly the same MIME types) works just fine under Firefox. Does it mean that Firefox is less strict about under which MIME type JavaScript is served?

Comment: @trejder Presumably. Back in the late-1990s and through to the mid-2000s, when self-hosting (especially by people who don't know how to configure their webserver software correctly) was more commonplace the situation with content-type headers and text-encoding was a mess - so to avoid having a poor UX most browsers were more accomodating. I'm surprised that Chrome rejects it outright though.